# How to get cropped image dimensions in a Fluid template in Typo3 v8

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

Is there a way to get the **actual image size** (width/height) of a **cropped image** ("Image manipulation" > [Open Editor]) in a **fluid template**?

All I can come up with is `{image.properties}` and `width` and `height`. But these are the dimensions of the original resource, not the cropped one. And there is of course an attribute `crop` which holds all the crop info:

```
{"default":{"cropArea":{"height":0.6431784107946027,"width":0.608,"x":0.037,"y":0.15592203898050974},"selectedRatio":"NaN","focusArea":null}}
```

But do I really have to find a way to parse this in fluid (if that's even possible)? Isn't there an official way to calculate the actual dimension of a generated image?

My use case is an image gallery component for which I need to explicitly state the image dimensions.

Comment: Why not simply render the images for a given crop variant using Fluid? Then the images will have their final cropped size used in the output automatically.

Comment: Fair point, but I need to render the image dimensions as inline javascript for the gallery component.

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3 Fluid, You can crop image like below. [See here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html)

```
<f:image src="{image ogject}" alt="Landscape" width="100c" height="100c" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I know, but that way I end up with an image tag – which I dont want (can be easily 100+ images, which would all be loaded at page load). I need the cropped width/height as a fluid variable to render a javascript variable as inline <script>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the VHS Media / SizeViewHelper https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/SizeViewHelper.html

```
<f:format.bytes><v:media.size path="{f:uri.image(image: mediaElement, width: 600) -> v:format.trim(characters: '/')}" /></f:format.bytes>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But actually I need the image dimensions ("actual image size (width/height)" of the cropped image). Just realized that my wording in the title is rather poor. I try to fix that.